# Расширение для класса в виде свойства C#

Tags: c#

Написал расширения для класса `ManualResetEvent`:

```
public static class ManualResetEventState
{
     public static bool IsPaused(this ManualResetEvent @event)
     {
         return !@event.WaitOne(0);
     }
}
```

Но хочу чтобы оно использовалось не как метод, а как свойство объекта.
Можно ли провернуть данную затею?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос кроется в названии данной механики, ведь зовется она не `Расширения` (`Extension`), а [Методы расширения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (`Extension Мethods`).

Comment: Пока это невозможно, возможно будет добавлено в следующих версиях языка

Comment: Возможно подойдут Partial классы